# Why does the edge case with -50 to 50 not work after iterating past -6? Removing duplicates from sorted linkedList

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I've tried solving this with two different algorithms and had people check them and everything seems fine but it doesn't work with an edge case from -50 to 50.

```
class Solution:
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        curr = head
        while curr is not None and curr.next is not None:
            if curr.next.val is curr.val:
                curr.next = curr.next.next
            else:
                curr = curr.next
        return head
```

another algorithm:

```
class Solution:
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        slowPtr = head
        fastPtr = head
        while fastPtr is not None and fastPtr.next is not None:
            if  fastPtr.next.val is not slowPtr.val:
                slowPtr.next = fastPtr.next
                slowPtr = slowPtr.next
            fastPtr = fastPtr.next
        if slowPtr is not None and slowPtr.next is not None:
            slowPtr.next = None
        return head
```

[image]

Comment: Show how you run it. Don't post pics

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st solution is fine except 1 thing,

```
class Solution:
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        curr = head
        while curr is not None and curr.next is not None:
            if curr.next.val == curr.val:
                curr.next = curr.next.next
            else:
                curr = curr.next
        return head
```

This line :

```
if curr.next.val == curr.val:
```

**"=="** is used for checking whether value of right operand is equal to value of left operand or not.
Whereas **"is"** used to check whether both are pointing to the same object or not.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your input!
But I am not following. My intention was to check if the values are the same. I am removing duplicate nodes and the linked list is sorted so I check If they have the same value. Is this not a correct approach? I am still new to this. Why would I need to check if they point to the same object? I am instead supposed to check if they contain the same number/value, am I right?

Comment: Your approach was correct, except that you have to use __==__ when comparing two values. Run the above code in answer and you will see it will work.